# sqlite filter by day of the week in one statement

Tags: sqlite

I would like to filter by day of the week (Thursday in my example) in one statement. The next statement works (please note that `date` is a column name):

```
SELECT CAST (strftime('%w', date) AS Integer) = 4 FROM sales WHERE id=123;
```

However, when I include the above filter I get no results:

```
SELECT * FROM sales WHERE id=123 AND (SELECT CAST (strftime('%w', date) AS Integer) = 4 FROM sales WHERE id=123) = 1;
```

Comment: The second statement (unless i missed something) will only return result if id=123 has date with the day of the week being 4. Otherwise, the inner select will not return 1.

Comment: @v010dya thanks for your comment. The db does have data with id=123 and day of the week 4 but returns nothing. Actually the first statement that works returns 1s and 0s.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Then you're comparing a result set with a single number. I don't think that's allowed.

Comment: The query is needlessly complex, but should work. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @CL thanks for your appreciation. How would you simplify it while keeping in mind that will be used in a prepared `C` statement?

Comment: Provide some sample data that demonstrates the problem. [This example works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/e6ee41/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I do not know why the previous code doesn't work I post an alternative working solution:

```
SELECT * FROM sales WHERE id=123 AND CAST (strftime('%w', date) AS Integer) = 4;
```