# SQLite - get last day of the week available when there are missing fridays

Tags: c++, sqlite

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904943/sqlite-filter-by-day-of-the-week-in-one-statement) question I was trying to filter my database by day of the week and I finally found a solution. However, when there are gaps in the data, in order to get at least one registry per week, I would need to get the registry of the last day available in that week.

As an example the statement for my new problem returns:

```
SELECT strftime('%W', date), date, stock FROM sales WHERE id=123 AND CAST (strftime('%w', date) AS Integer) = 5;
```

Since I usually run the statement through the `C++ API` I would appreciate that the solution sticks with just one statement when possible.

Note: if you run the statement above through the C++ API please note that when preparing the statement the variable `'%w'` in `strftime` should be `"%w"` otherwise it will not work (it took me I while until I found the problem).

EDIT: these are example records:

daily data (week index|date|record):

```
09|2016-03-01|1219.0
09|2016-03-02|1255.0
09|2016-03-03|1298.0
09|2016-03-04|1309.0
10|2016-03-07|1344.0
10|2016-03-08|1305.0
10|2016-03-09|1304.0
10|2016-03-10|1258.0
10|2016-03-11|1298.0
11|2016-03-14|1304.0
11|2016-03-15|1274.0
11|2016-03-16|1283.0
11|2016-03-17|1315.0
11|2016-03-18|1296.0
12|2016-03-21|1286.0
12|2016-03-22|1280.0
12|2016-03-23|1246.0
12|2016-03-24|1223.0
13|2016-03-29|1214.0
13|2016-03-30|1239.0
13|2016-03-31|1220.0
13|2016-04-01|1183.0
```

Weekly (from the query above):

```
09|2016-03-04|1309.0
10|2016-03-11|1298.0
11|2016-03-18|1296.0
13|2016-04-01|1183.0
```

I would like to get the following:

```
09|2016-03-04|1309.0
10|2016-03-11|1298.0
11|2016-03-18|1296.0
12|2016-03-24|1223.0
13|2016-04-01|1183.0
```

Comment: If you have a self answered solution for a specific problem you should still stick with the Q&A format required here.

Comment: @user0042 could you please be a little bit more constructive and tell me what is wrong with my question?

Comment: There is no question. There's a problem and you gave a solution. Ask a question stating a specific problem and post your solution as an answer for it.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Comment: @user0042 There is a question, possibly with less information than what is needed to answer so I have tried to complete my question. However, instead of telling what you're missing to provide an answer you are so constructive that focus in downvoting and voting to close, very helpful!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the record with the largest date for each week index:

```sql
SELECT week_index,
       MAX(date),
       value
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY week_index;
```